# [C#]How to write log in runtime error situation?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

**How to write log in Runtime Error situation?**

I want to know where the error occurred at source code.(When I execute `.exe` file)

(I don't use `Serial debugging`)

Comment: Write it to a notepad(.txt) file or Implement log4net. Refer: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: If you use log4net, you could just put as log message the information you want to identify where the error has happened, and what exception was thrown. Check https://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use print the exception using Debug.WriteLine

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Writeline(ex.ToString());
}
```

There is a catch in using for Compact framework, it wont have the same behaviour. But you can try this.

> On Windows CE, any information passed to Debug.Write is displayed in a
>   temporary console window on the device. The console window
>   automatically opens on the fist call to Debug.Write and closes
>   immediately after the application exits. The console window can be
>   kept open by placing a breakpoint at the end of the application's
>   Main() function, to prevent the application from completely exiting.

More details - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446495.aspx